# Online office with password protection?

Tags: web-apps, security, office

I have few confidential work/excel files which is password protected. I usually use Google Docs/Drive to keep my Office files, but they doesn't seems to support password protected files.

Is there any online free option too keep and change password protected (MS Office) document?

Comment: What's the problem with Google Docs? Don't you need to use your password to access your documents? Or did you forget to specify that you want to be able to share documents with others?

Comment: I cannot use password protected file there

Answer (score 1):

Apparently with **Office 365** Enterprise Edition by Microsoft "you can create a password-protected portal to share large, hard-to-e-mail files both inside and outside your organization". At least this is what they claim, but then you'll need to pay about $20 a month if that's an option.

I really doubt you'll be able to find a free option for this but good luck!